# coc.nvim - no rome found in your project root

Tags: ubuntu, vim

I have the latest version of Ubuntu and recently installed vim. I'm trying to get coc.nvim to work. See https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim . This is an autocompletion package (and then some) for vim and nvim.

I installed the package but when I execute

`:CocInstall coc-rome`

to get specific settings for JavaScript, I get this error:

`[coc.nvim] No rome found  in your project root.`

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Hey this is a vim question, please post it on https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually what solved my problem was using coc-tsserver instead of coc-rome.

Answer (score 0):

Your project doesn't has Rome installed, you need to [install and setup Rome](https://romefrontend.dev/#installation) for your project when you using `coc-rome`.